# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') when using randomizedSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas, mlp, randomized-algorithm

I am trying to use RandomizedSearchCV from sklearn on an MLPRegressor model, and I have scaled the data using standardScaler. The code for the model is presented below. When I try to run the code I get this error from the ann_random.fit(x_train,y_train.flatten()):

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I have checked if the dataset contains any nan or infinite values, but there seems like there is none. I have also tried to run the code with an MLPRegressor model with the given hyperparametes:

```
model = MLPRegressor(activation='relu', solver='adam', hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100,50), max_iter=500)
```

and the code works fine when I run the MLPRegressor model without the randomizedsearch.

What can be the cause of this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

before tarin model first take look at your data :
first find missing value with thid code :

```
df.isnall().sum()
```

if in your data have missing value remove them or fill them

```
df = df.dropna()
```

second: normalize your data between 0 and 1
i hope my solution help you

Comment: I have tried to check if there exist null values, but there is none. I have also already normalized the data. Could there be any other reason?

Comment: can you describe your data wite describe() and tell me ?

Comment: I removed the sgd solver from the hyperparameter grid and it works fine now.